# Normalmap generation from Heightmap in GLSL Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, fft, heightmap

i am currently working on an ocean rendering system with OpenGL. the heightmap is computed with fft and looks nice. but i have some issues by generating the normalmap from the heightmap. the normalmap is created in a fragment shader by using the precomputed heightmap as a texture. To compute a normal i use the sobel filter, here is my code:

```
 // z0 -- z1 -- z2
 // |     |     |
 // z3 -- h  -- z4
 // |     |     |
 // z5 -- z6 -- z7

// Sobel Filter
normal.z = 1/normalStrength;
normal.x = z2 + 2*z4 + z7 - z0 - 2*z3 - z5;
normal.y = z5 + 2*z6 + z7 -z0 - 2*z1 - z2;
```

z0 - z7 are heightvalues from the heightmap texture.
the normals are computed correctly, but in the normal texture there are appearing kind of steps/seams of islands, which destroys the smoothness of the normalmap. the heightmap looks very smooth with no seams/edges.

i think there are some numerical mistakes respectively boundaries with the heightvalues, but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: I suspect two possibilities: 1. The normal map should be the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient) of the heightmap, and the Sobel operator is just an approximation of this; it might not be a good enough approximation in your case, or 2. You are dealing with an RGB8 texture and therefore only have 255 discrete levels of height in your heightmap, which may not be enough precision for your usage.

Comment: You may want to post more information though, and perhaps show pictures of the heightmap, normal map, and the end result.